# Need to download the html page as PDF

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sas

I have some cross-tabs in HTML page and I want to download those in PDF format. I have generated the same report in SAS reporting standard, but as the PDF and HTML doesn't render one another in SAS, so trying to develop a JavaScript piece of code, so that I can embed the same in SAS in order to convert the HTML contents into PDF.

I have developed the below scripts in JavaScript, but I am not a expert in JavaScript.

```js
var options = {
  "url": "/pdf/generate",
  "data": "data=" + $("#content").html(),
  "type": "post",
}
$.ajax(options)


$html = $_POST['data'];
$pdf = html2pdf($html);

header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); //check this is the proper header for pdf
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='some.pdf';");
echo $pdf;

$(function() {

  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  $('#cmd').click(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML(
      $('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      },
      function() {
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
      }
    );

  });
});
```

```html
<title>HTML TO PDF Rendering</title>


<div id="content">

  <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

  <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

I tried to run the above piece of code in online Javascript snippet, though it's not giving an error, but clicking on the Generate PDF button is not downloading the page into PDF format.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You set the MIME type to `application/pdf`. What is the actual type of the document that gets downloaded? It is an html document or a pdf document?

Comment: I don't see where you includes of `jQuery` and JavaScript library containing the unicorn 'html2pdf'.  Even if it were I double html2pdf could recreate the page itself from just the post data visited upon it.  What software is used to create the html page and can you show the code used to create the cross-tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case perhaps.  Use `SAS` to send the same procedural output simultaneously to both html and pdf destinations.  Each destination will create a separate document.  In the html document add a link to the pdf document.  When both files are served as static content they should reside in the same served folder.

```
ods html file = 'c:\temp\xtab.html' style=journal;
ods pdf file = 'c:\temp\xtab.pdf' style=journal;

ods noresults;

options nodate nonumber nocenter;

proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars;
  class make model type;
  table make, type=''*N='';
  where make like 'M%';
run;

ods pdf close;

ods html text='<a href="xtab.pdf">Link goes here</a>';

ods html close;

ods results;

options noxmin noxwait noxsync;
%sysexec start "My Browser" c:\temp\xtab.html;
```

When your browser opens, click on the link to see the pdf version.

Add more details to the questions if the content is generated dynamically in SAS by way of a prompt and stored process.

You could also have a *master* page that displays the differing content in an `iframe`

```
<html>
<title>demo</title>
<body>
<button id="asHtml" onclick="asHtml()"> Show HTML output </button>
<button id="asPDF"  onclick="asPDF()"> Show PDF output </button>
<iframe id="theTabulate" width="100%" height="90%">
</iframe>
<script>
function asHtml() {
  document.getElementById("theTabulate").src = "xtab.html";
}
function asPDF() {
  document.getElementById("theTabulate").src = "xtab.pdf";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You would need much clearer specifications from your output consumer before delving into any more sophisticated.

Comment: Yeah, Richard. The reports gets generated with a Stored process with Date and Month prompts. 

We had developed the report as per the requirement. The report should able to be downloaded in Excel, word and PDF format.

The excel and Word are getting downloaded properly and reports are getting visible with proper layout in those, but while downloading the PDF, it's throwing the browser prompt to save the .pdf file, but while opening it, it's not opening and saying that file is corrupt.

Comment: Tried to reach SAS Tech, but they had informed that PDF and HTML render can't be possible in one space, so was trying to develop a javascript, so that in the click event of the PDF icon I could embed the same.

Comment: The below is the reply from them:

SAS cannot generate the output in PDF if we are using the html tags to generate the reports 
    > (which cannot be achieved without an HTML tags in our case). 
 
The internal format of a PDF file is completely different from the format of an HTML file.  
So, HTML statements cannot be embedded (and resolved as HTML) in a PDF file.
That is a PDF requirement.  
As an analogy you cannot mix the Japanese language with the English language
in a paragraph without creating a mess.  You cannot mix PDF with HTML in the
same file without creating a mess.

Comment: At a minimum you would have to have a 'master' html page with an `iframe` to render the different content-types. I speculate most modern browsers would be able to.

Comment: Richard, can you please give a background on how we can achieve something with Iframe.

Can you replicate the same example for proc tabulate in Iframe? I mean is it possible?

Just a demo if you can give, it will be really helpful.

Comment: So if the report is only generated as HTML why do you need to save it as PDF?

Comment: Add the stored process code to the question, that would be most helpful.  How large is the content output ? A page, several hundred pages ?  You might have to tweak the `_webout` fileref in some manner if you are getting corrupt output for `ODS PDF` destination, or perhaps use function `STPSRV_HEADER()` to set the proper content-type.

Comment: Yeah, the report is one page report. We used the _webout to do the same. It's the requirement that report should be downloaded in 3 formats that's excel, word and PDF.

Code I might not able to share, but yes I can share the screenshot for excel type output format.

Comment: You can have a check with the code what we had did to get the PDF icon to download the PDF format page. The same macro being called in the stored process.

Comment: Richard, you can have a check with the below code inside the snippet and if anything clicks out.  Do let me know...

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

```js
%macro mac_buttons_ods(
   mcv_style          = ERS,  /* Select the SAS style you want to use.  default = ers */ 
   mcv_dest           = HTML, /* PDF, RTF, XML, EXCEL, PANEL, SPECIAL, TEXT or TABLE */ 
   mcv_tag_options    = ,
   mcv_excel_options  = %str(options(sheet_label="ERS" sheet_interval="none" frozen_headers="yes" embedded_titles="yes")), 
   mcv_ods_options  = %str(),
   mcv_title          = ERS, /* Enter the text you want to see in the title area of the browser window.*/ 
   mcv_portal_only    = no,
   mcv_mode           = PROD, /* PROD: mprint mlogic symbolgen will be turned off otherwise they will be turned on. */
   mcv_param          =,/*all the parameters to pass in url*/
   ) ;


   %global mcv_stp_name 
           mcv_ers_url 
           mcv_sasweb 
           _odsdest _odsoptions _odsstyle _odsstylesheet _program _url mcv_filename 
           mcv_back mcv_forward mcv_pdf mcv_excel mcv_word mcv_print mcv_rerun mcv_close
           ;
   %local mcv_style 
          mcv_dest 
          mcv_tag_options 
          mcv_excel_options 
          mcv_title 
          mcv_ods_options 
          mcv_portal_only 
          mcv_mode ;

   *ProcessBody ;
   options minoperator ;

   %* Only use this macro if running as a stored process ;
   %if %superq(_program) = %then %return ;;


   libname ersstyle '/apps/usr/ERS/styles' access=readonly ;
   ods path ersstyle.templat(read) sasuser.templat(update) sashelp.tmplmst(read) ;
   ods escapechar = '^' ;

   %let _odsstyle   = &mcv_style. ;
   %let mcv_sasweb  = https://&_srvname.:&_srvport./ ;

   data _null_ ;
     call symputx('mcv_stp_name',scanq("&_program.",countc("&_program.","/"),'/')) ;
   run ;
%mac_assign_lib;
   
    %let mcv_back = "<button class='NAV' onclick=history.go(-1)%str(;) title='Go Back 1 Page'><img src='/images/left.png' /></button>" ;
    %let mcv_forward ="<button class='NAV' onclick=history.go(+1)%str(;) title='Go Forward 1 Page'><img src='/images/right.png' /></button>"; 
    %let mcv_pdf     = "<button class='NAV' onclick=location.href='do?_program=%sysfunc(urlencode(&_program.))&mcv_param.%str(&)_odsdest=PDF' title='Click to Download to PDF.' ><img src='/images/pdf.png' /></button>";
    %let mcv_excel   = "<button class='NAV' onclick=location.href='do?_program=%sysfunc(urlencode(&_program.))&mcv_param.%str(&)_odsdest=EXCEL' title='Click to Download to Excel.'><img src='/images/excel_small.png' /></button>";
    %let mcv_word   =  "<button class='NAV' onclick=location.href='do?_program=%sysfunc(urlencode(&_program.))&mcv_param.%str(&)_odsdest=RTF' title='Click to Download to Word'><img src='/images/word.png' /></button>";
    %let mcv_print   = "<button class='NAV' onclick=window.print(); title='Click to Print report.'><img src='/images/print.png' /></button>";
    %let mcv_rerun   =  "<button class='NAV' onclick=window.location.reload(); title='Click to Re-Run report.'> <img src='/images/rerun.png' /></button>";
    %let mcv_close   = "<button class='NAV' onclick=self.close(); title='Click to Close window.'><img src='/images/close.png' /></button>";

   

   %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_portal_only)) = YES and %superq(_result) = PACKAGE_TO_ARCHIVE %then %do ;
         %stpbegin ;
         ods text = "^{style [fontsize=14pt]&c_stp_name.}" ;
         ods text = "^{style [fontsize=14pt]Can only be viewed on the ERS Portal.}" ;
   %end ;
   %else %do ;
      %if %upcase(%superq(_odsdest)) ne HTML and 
          %upcase(%superq(_odsdest)) > %str() %then %let mcv_dest = &_odsdest. ;;

      %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) = EXCEL %then %do ;
         data _null_ ;
            rc = stpsrv_header('Content-type','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') ;
            rc = stpsrv_header('Content-disposition',"attachment; filename=&mcv_stp_name..xlsx") ;
         run ;

         ods excel file = _webout ;
         ods excel style = &mcv_style. %if %superq(mcv_excel_options) > %str() %then &mcv_excel_options. ;; 
      %end ;
      %else %let _odsdest = &mcv_dest. ;;
       %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) = PANEL   %then %let _odsdest = tagsets.htmlpanel ;
       %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) = TABLE   %then %let _odsdest = tagsets.tableeditor ;
      %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) = SPECIAL %then %let _odsdest = tagsets.special ;

      %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) =HTML OR  %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest))=PANEL OR %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest))=TABLE OR %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest))=SPECIAL %then %do ;
       %include "/apps/usr/ERS/MacroLibrary/tableeditor.tpl";
/*    ods tagsets.tableeditor file=_webout style= &mcv_tag_options.;*/
         %let _odsoptions = file=_webout (title='ERS') style= &mcv_style. &mcv_tag_options. ;

      %end ;
      %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) = PDF %then %do ;
         %let _odsoptions = notoc &mcv_ods_options. ;
         data _null_ ;
            rc = stpsrv_header('Content-disposition',"attachment; filename=&mcv_stp_name..pdf") ;
         run ;
      %end ;
      %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) = RTF %then %do ;
   %let _ODSOPTIONS= KEEPN; 
   
         data _null_ ;
            rc = stpsrv_header('Content-disposition',"attachment; filename=&mcv_stp_name..doc") ;
         run ;
      %end ;
      %if %upcase(%superq(mcv_dest)) ne EXCEL %then %stpbegin ;;

   %end ;

   %if %upcase(&mcv_mode) ne PROD %then options mlogic mprint symbolgen ;
   %else                                options nomlogic nomprint nosymbolgen ;;
%mend mac_buttons_ods;
```

[Excel Output Image format the same is needed in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E08Hm.png)